# building GLEW for vs2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, glew

i want to built glew for vs2015.

I tried the cmake from http://glew.sourceforge.net/build.html
and tried to convert an existing vs solution. both fail for various reasons.

Is there a working vs2015 solution for glew on the internet, or a cmake that does not fail miserably?

Comment: I don't see any references to cmake on the page that you linked. Am I missing something? I'm curious- why don't you first try asking for help with the documented build approaches instead of looking for something not blessed by the project maintainers?